How to ensure fixed 32-bit storage for enum variables in C across different platforms?
I'm working on a C project that needs to store enum values within a struct at a consistent memory offset across platforms. Since enum storage size in C can vary depending on the compiler and platform, I'm facing difficulties ensuring that enum variables are stored in exactly 32 bits.
Here’s what I tried:
typedef enum {
    value1,
    value2,
    value3,
    dummy_value = 0x7FFFFFFF  // Ensures at least 32-bit range
} my_enum;

I added dummy_value = 0x7FFFFFFF to the enum, hoping this would force the compiler to use 32 bits for storage. However, on some platforms, the compiler may still allocate 64 bits for the enum, which causes inconsistencies in the memory layout of my structs.
Here's what my struct looks like:
typedef struct {
    my_enum enum_field; // This may not always be 32 bits
    int other_field;
} MyStruct;

My goal is to ensure that enum_field always occupies exactly 32 bits, regardless of the platform.
What I've Tried:

Defining a large dummy_value in the enum, but this doesn't always enforce 32-bit storage.
I considered using int32_t for the storage type, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach for using enums in a platform-independent way.

Questions:

Is there a reliable way to ensure that enum values are stored in exactly 32 bits in C?
Would using int32_t in place of my_enum in the struct be a good practice, or is there a better approach?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Since the C23 standard enumerations allows you to specify the underlying type (like e.g. int32_t). Before C23 there's no way to guarantee it.

If you want a standardized way of dealing with "enumerations" that are portable across compilers, platforms and C standard versions, the only way is to use a fixed-width integer type variable (like the above mentioned int32_t, which to nitpick came with the C99 standard and might not exists for compilers using older standards) and macros defining the enumeration values.

This question is similar to: Specifying size of enum type in C. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If size matters, enum is a bad choice.

".... a struct at a consistent memory offset across platforms." Remember that compilers may add padding between struct members.


Is there a reliable way to ensure that enum values are stored in exactly 32 bits in C?

Until C23 - no.
From C23 - we have enumeration of fixed underlying type, so you can use:
//-----------vvvvvvvvv--
typedef enum : int32_t {
    value1,
    value2,
    value3,
} my_enum;


Would using int32_t in place of my_enum in the struct be a good practice, or is there a better approach?

It has disadvantages, as you lose the advantage of a real enum. I would not say it's good practice in general.
But if you cannot use C23 this is your only choice to reliably ensure the values are 32 bit.
A side note:
You also mentioned using the enum in a struct.
Keep in mind struct size is not guaranteed since the compiler can add padding bytes.
In order to overcome it you will need to use compiler specific pragmas etc. which are not really portable.
For complete portabilty you will also have to address Endianness.

This answer is incomplete. OP observed the enum size with a struct definition; given what's going on here it's highly likely OP also needs packed structs.

@Joshua it's true that the OP mentioned using a struct. But both the title of the question, and the 2 questions under the "Questions:" section at the end refer only to the enum issue, so I focused on that (since a post here should focus on one issue). In any case I edited now and added a side note about the struct issue.


I added dummy_value = 0x7FFFFFFF to the enum, hoping this would force the compiler to use 32 bits for storage.

This doesn't do you any good. Enumeration constants (value1 etc) are always of type int. The allocated enumeration objects are compiler-specific though and may be smaller than int if the value range of the enumeration constants could fit in a smaller type. So all you achieved with 0x7FFFFFFF was to ensure that the enum is at least 32 bits.
Also you can't get larger types than int for that reason, value1 = 0x100000000 is invalid C on a machine with 32 bit int.
This poor design has been a glaring language defect in C since the dawn of time. Like structs, enums are not really portable or suitable to represent an exact memory layout.
Fixes involve using macros instead, for example:
#define value1 (uint32_t)0
#define value2 (uint32_t)1

typedef uint32_t my_type;

The new C standard "C23" that just went live finally fixes this defect though. In C23 you can declare the enum as typedef enum : uint32_t and then everything turns into uint32_t as expected. You can also have larger ranges than int now. Experimental versions of gcc and clang support C23 partially, including the new enum feature. So if your product can stomach numerous compiler bugs, it might be worth considering C23.


I'm working on a C project that needs to store enum values within a
struct at a consistent memory offset across platforms.

It can't be done as the compiler can add padding between fields and enums pre C23 can have any inter type.
To archive it you need to use the compiler specific pragmas and attributes and by definition, it is not portable.
If you want to be really portable you need to use the char array, endianess independent reading and writing functions.
